# Kotlin based Spring RabbitListener produces endlessloop trying to send back `kotlin.Unit`

Tags: spring, kotlin, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

We have a RabbitListener implemented in Kotlin. The method returns Unit, so I dont expect Spring to send a result but we are getting the following error message. It looks like Spring tries to iterprete Unit as the result and send a rabbit message back:

```
2021-04-16 16:39:21 
msg="Execution of Rabbit message listener failed." thread="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#0-2" level=WARN logger="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler" exception="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1746)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1636)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1551)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor64.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at brave.spring.rabbit.TracingRabbitListenerAdvice.invoke(TracingRabbitListenerAdvice.java:108)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.$Proxy146.invokeListener(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1539)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1530)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1474)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:967)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:913)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:83)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1288)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1194)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.ReplyFailureException: Failed to send reply with payload 'InvocationResult [returnValue=kotlin.Unit, returnType=class java.lang.Object, bean=com.xxx.EventHandler@4aaf6902, method=public java.lang.Object com.xxx.EventHandler.receiveMessage(org.springframework.amqp.core.Message)]'
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.doHandleResult(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:476)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.handleResult(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:400)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandlerAndProcessResult(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:152)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:135)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1632)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SimpleMessageConverter only supports String, byte[] and Serializable payloads, received: kotlin.Unit
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.SimpleMessageConverter.createMessage(SimpleMessageConverter.java:164)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.createMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.toMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.convert(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:519)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.buildMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:257)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.doHandleResult(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:464)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
" time="2021-04-16 14:39:21,726"
```

here a simplified version of the RabbitLister:

```
@Component
class EventHandler {

    @RabbitListener(queues = ["someQueue"])
    fun receiveMessage(message: Message): Unit {
        log.debug("Received message")
    }
}
```

We use Spring Boot 2.4.4, Spring Rabbit 2.3.6 and Spring Framework 5.3.6

debugging the issue, I got the following result: [image]

Comment: Make it just like this then: `fun receiveMessage(message: Message) {`! What is the point to specify `Unit` explicitly?

Comment: Even with `: Unit` I see `void` in IntelliJ as the return type.

Comment: I added the versions

Comment: In this case, the Kotlin version is more important than the Spring versions.

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using?

This works fine for me (with and without the `Unit` return type)...

```java
@RabbitListener(queues = ["foo"])
open fun listen(data: String?): Unit {
    println(data)
}
```

Even with `: Unit`, I see `void` as the return type and `null`:

[image]

Comment: This was with spring-rabbit 2.3.6 and Kotlin 1.4.32.

Comment: I debugged it down to the point where the Exception is thrown and added the result to my question. I also get return type `void`, but the returnValue is `kotlin.Unit`